# Who are all these superheros in Avengers: Endgame poster?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, avengers-endgame

Recently I got my hands on [IGN's *Avengers: Endgame* poster](https://www.facebook.com/ign/photos/basw.Abr5rwxln93KuesMvGzSQcKtuT53TmFRPpATTZ8iAzFfwC0X87WBRaxld8d283M415hZfV9FJKkqEAQKifkQcemoqr79yyNUo7NLDihgcBfBxvkGb5u0TcHGJozjJ8yRRmo.10156372154761633.1762035317382407.1296550720361155/10156372154761633/?type=1&opaqueCursor=Abo7AQZCp61R5apgevCPwA85M9LvtHL8-UnGPUTLINNRWVpNR0ub1tRbK0ZEfp12rpz6vwPyf6wKJODAb6Hr8lzmVKrRqWGIX6N1WbJcW33oUhNVpwuI1UPVDxUa4_pcNTZuEgAS4O8Mcib-uq1rfvNe2mvr7rbouY6rP3YZ0GeitJThxPloUYiZMwR4lecOo16pc2Eq81d8NrB_fhAJ1BZjmfxeWqyiEs-0j5uLOPzDcKWHf7mREiy-c4GT1PmPLrnwlUO1yUS-yBOgWDPLA6GM6UmJpUZE5g2x0nHnUaMBEGjhcSHetptBjgc8FnopKDnXDflXs8m7ztcXXfybAghrrvRelRayJ23wQj4HGlBBgKUsENJYQP23XVJpY2Wd170y69QqmccaDHMt5l80EFYkCIpQ-0iZO8ZIFk71pm76M22gHf5GLZo4yTE6UFCXYbuvT_uhjJnc9ArQQdFF8iXXBePF4luDZjlg_fCEUWZnlLm5g-FgDb2aFNtdsrRWu5exdYppk5Mg4BwAlcFzNhz8Robrx12U4K2KY5kF_zEHiV7aX_a1bAo6FXsFdEBPXEWT2_3wZQkMzbLtWkNwpnJb6GoEGQVms2MbdDwveFhe72PMFFleNrHWLkbbi4-kLSanibTrQs2_FdfQQ_bm6kNoZIuJeGHHzwaK_iYcbAbasNnaT0JR-Ehv46yK8mI_Db6UjhmNExapVNciao86OscWMmUc8YSiSTXyVxs13abvyqn_5mQkhIiB3a9qmOuLeIpzDuBfuagfeCVnMujAEagOz7dp5pki_1muNL9ronEgU-4Z03TihRUKjlGTZ_lx1Z2FaauQXt_7qsrvPYEUZlKsHqOIlie94dqV3S5u1vzORNealHChLdLR1nbIYzaxloJ8hXhH5bV_H7RvCpHDirxorDyvZUEA2qa0B4YZiyztyRIdnmc10E4OTaJm3pYeih4_WXb2ZB_Og-kfgkGhDx6pUjdq-Rm5Lv5aYlw2ACzMc27grfmODBRd-GwPEYGNLck&theater), which they made themselves:

[image]

I can identify majority of them but not all. Who are all these 13 superheroes?

Comment: Is this an official poster? I have never seen it anywhere

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 I got it from some IGN FB page, will share the link in evening later

Comment: I took almost a minute to realise that Spiderman wasn't a Christmas angel decoration. Clearly the festivities are getting to me...

Comment: This whole poster can be construed as a spoiler.  Now we know that the disintegrated characters are still "alive" somewhere (Soul Stone probably) and are in the next movie.  I for one did not want to be spoiled like this.

Comment: @TonyDuran If this is a fan creation (and I strongly suspect it is - the only "official" one I've seen came out with the trailer) then it's not a spoiler, as it's based on guesswork.

Comment: @TonyDuran in that way, the entire imdb page for EndGame, is a spoiler.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 I doubt it, they're all standard "renders" (cutouts) of the heroes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[image]

1. Maria Hill
2. Winter Soldier
3. Nick Fury
4. Scarlet Witch
5. Groot
6. Black Panther
7. Gamora ( kid version)
8. Spider-Man
9. Dr. Strange
10. Mantis
11. Star-Lord
12. Drax
13. Wasp

Comment: 6 definitely looks more like Iron Man, but it's actually Black panther you're right. https://imgc.allpostersimages.com/img/print/posters/avengers-infinity-war-black-panther_a-G-15492600-0.jpg

Weird that Panther uses Ironman's pose.

Comment: no, as you can see, they are inside the soul stone universe (because of the color of the image).

Comment: Good pickup. He still has the same pose as Ironman though. I already agree that it's Black panther.

Comment: @eLRuLL right, Iron Man wouldn't be within the Soul Stone according to Infinity War. That also explains the absence of Ant-Man and Captain America.

Comment: wait... but didn't these guys get snapped away by Thanos in IW? I mean, everyone except Scarlet witch I think

Comment: @Malky.Kid They all did. What's your point? Did you expect them to not be in the next movie?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, by virtue that they got snapped out of existense. Also with that theory that the contracts for these actors for their respective characters aren't ending so this film would star the ones left.

Comment: @Malky.Kid given the already-announced Scarlet Witch series and Spider-Man film, they were obviously going to appear in Avengers 4.

Comment: @OrangeDog okay, okay

Comment: Wow sucks to be Falcon

Answer (score 5):

[image: I took the lliberty of using the same image]

I have no idea about 1, yet going by elimination it must be Agent Hill( maybe holding a gun or something)

2 is surely Winter Soldier (though how he got his gun down in the Soul Stone World is wierd since it didn't disintegrate)

3 is surely Nick Fury. You can see the same pose in this Winter Soldier poster.

[image: Same pose]

4 is Scarlet Witch, going by her dress and floating ability.

5 has to be Groot, going by his head shape and broad feet.

6 is a bit tough but I'll go with Black Panther by the body shape and pose that suggests claws.

7 is undoubtedly Young Gamora.

8 again is Spiderman with no doubt.

9 is Dr. Strange, by the cape.

10 is surely Mantis,

11 Quill,

12 Drax and

13 The Wasp.

Shame they didn't include Falcon.